# Pointwise Confidence Regions in Gaussian Process

Tags: confidence-interval, gaussian-process, multivariate-normal-distribution

In Rasmussen's Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning, the joint distribution of noisy function observations, $y=f(x)+\epsilon$, at $x$ and noiseless function evaluations, $f^\star$, at unseen points, $x^\star$, given the hyperparameters of the kernel and the noise variance is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y \\
f^\star
\end{bmatrix}\sim 
N\biggr(0,
\begin{bmatrix}
K(x,x)+\sigma^2I & K(x,x^\star)\\
K(x,x^\star) & K(x^\star,x^\star)
\end{bmatrix}\biggr )
$$

Rasmussen uses the above to derive $p(f^\star|y,X,X^\star)$, which Rasmussen refers to as the predictive distribution. He appears to construct $95\%$ confidence regions by taking the pointwise mean and 1.96 times the standard deviation given by the conditional distribution of $f^\star$. What is the interpretation of these pointwise intervals around the mean and its relationship to $f$?

I believe the predictive distribution above is a distribution over functions which describes the set of plausible values $f^\star$ could take on if I sampled from the conditional. It isn't clear to me though that these intervals are directly related to the realized values of $f$ which occur in the training points. Is that accurate?

Comment: What is "Rasmussen"? Some paper from 1872? A highly cited paper from 2003, "Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning"? The book with same title, by Rasmussen and Williams? You could give a link, and the publication year (just once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of it like this: a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is a mapping $f: x \to y$. We use Gaussian Processes to model random functions $f \sim \mathcal{GP}$, where the mapping is non-deterministic. GP takes some points $x$ and the realizations of the functions $f(x) = y$ to learn the random function $f$. Using the symbols you used in your question $x$ are the observed inputs, and $x_*$ are the new, unobserved ones. The intervals describe the distribution over functions (as modeled with GP). We can evaluate the GP over arbitrary inputs $x_*$ to get the draws from the mappings for those inputs. So "the points" are just the mappings that we happened to look at, but GP can be evaluated for any input $x_*$ and tell us what is the distribution of the realizations of $f$ at those points.

Comment: Okay, got it. The intervals outline the distribution of the realizations of $f$ at the unobserved points. The GP defines a non-deterministic mapping from $x\rightarrow y$, but once I sample from the GP, that function is fixed? Would it be wrong to say that?

Comment: @user1848065 the sample would be a realization of the random function, the same as running `rnorm()` in R would produce a sample that is a realization of the Gaussian random variable.